# entire CI super object showing up in Exception trace

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception

hope someone can help with this.

Whenever I `print_r` an Exception thrown in my Codeigniter site, the entire CI 'super object' shows up in the trace. I wouldn't care too much, since I won't normally be printing out the Exception for users to see, but my concern is sensitive information is in the trace. For example, my DB username and password, session Id, and encryption key, along with other trivial things like the entire calendar class, or the entire pagination class. along with these security concerns, the mere length of the exception can make it hard/annoying to troubleshoot, and find the info i actually care about.

i don't know enough about Exceptions to know if this is a bug or a feature, so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this. If I have no luck here, I'll probably submit it as an issue on CI's github.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using `print_r()` to output to the server's error log instead of the browser. You can do this using the `error_log()` function like below:

`error_log(print_r($your_exception_here, true));`

The second `true` parameter on `print_r()` makes it return a string instead of outputting straight to the browser automatically.

This obviously means you have to check your error log instead of a quick look in the browser, but the extra step is probably worth it for the security and/or user experience.

Comment: the concern is not really how I output it, but why the information is in the exception to begin with.

Comment: I would imagine an Exception should include it so it can be used as a stack trace (of sorts). If the presumption is that it will never be shown to the user (which it obviously shouldn't) then providing full details of the context in which the Exception occurred makes sense.